# Как отфильтровать запрос по трем таблицам за определенный промежуток времени?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Дано: PostgreSQL

Таблица link с колонкой id.
Таблица campaigns c колонкой link_id (ссылается на таблицу 1).
Таблица click с колонкой link_id (ссылается на таблицу 1) и колонкой created_at (дата).

Необходимо проверить что отсутствуют такие записи таблицы link:

- у которых нет связанных записей в таблице campaigns
- у которых нет связанных записей в таблице click за последние три месяца

```
SELECT link.id link_id,
       campaigns.link_id campaigns_link_id,
       click.link_id click_link_id
FROM link
FULL JOIN campaigns
ON link.id = campaigns.link_id
JOIN click
ONlink.id = click.link_id

WHERE campaigns.link_id is null
AND
click.created_at >= '2023-08-16 09:16:41'
;
```

Этот запрос выводит записи из таблицы link у которых ЕСТЬ связанные записи с таблицей click за последние три месяца.
Я никак не могу придумать что нужно изменить, чтобы получить линки у которых НЕТ связанных записей с таблицей click за последние три месяца.

Comment: Простой SELECT с двумя NOT EXISTS во WHERE.

Comment: Можно подробнее пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про `LEFT JOIN`, и особенно о том, чем отличаются условия в `WHERE` от условий в `LEFT JOIN`. Если кратко, `WHERE` действует на всё предложение FROM, а условие в JOIN только на условие присоединения конкретной таблицы.
Тогда как-то так:

```
SELECT link.id link_id,
       campaigns.link_id campaigns_link_id,
       click.link_id click_link_id
FROM link
  LEFT JOIN campaigns ON link.id = campaigns.link_id
  LEFT JOIN click ON link.id = click.link_id
    AND click.created_at >= '2023-08-16 09:16:41'
WHERE 
  campaigns.link_id is null AND click.link_id is null
```

Но, если в таблице link записей много, возможно выгодней будет использовать NOT EXISTS или EXCEPT, надо смотреть на конкретный данных.